# Can I return formated json inside a stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, .net-core-3.1

In .netcore 3.1, I have web API endpoint that returns a stream.
I populate the stream with Json string. Can I display Indented text on the browser

In Starup.cs, and in the configure services method I have:

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented);
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public Stream Get()
{
        // Receiving a string and not an object. 
        // the shape  of the object is unknown to me 
        string test = "{ \"mydata\":[{ \"data\":[{ \"x\":1,\"y\":0}],\"frq]\":12}],\"success\":true,\"error_message\":\"\"}";
        string pretty = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test,Formatting.Indented);
        return new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test));
}
```

I inspected the 'pretty' variable using visual studio debugger, JSON viewer instead of text and I noticed that is placing \" instead of \r\n

I am using Newtonsoft.Json

I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson v3.1.9 installed

Comment: Do the format in the client side. Formating consumes extra data and is generally not needed for computer consumtion. Only apply formating when you intend to display it to final users.

Comment: @Alejandro My Helperclass method is returning the stream to my controller, how can I format this stream. should I change my herlper method to return the json instead?

Comment: Can you post the content of the string of serialized object?

Comment: @Alejandro updated the question

Comment: @Brain Rogers. this is a test to prove 'pretty' isnt getting formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

So based on the code example you provided you just want to format existing json. You can do it by parsing it to `JObject` and back to json:

```
string test = "{ \"mydata\":[{ \"data\":[{ \"x\":1,\"y\":0}],\"frq]\":12}],\"success\":true,\"error_message\":\"\"}";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(test);
var stream = new MemoryStream();
jObject.WriteTo(new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(stream)));
return stream;
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

`.AddJsonOptions` configures serializer for the objects returned from the controller actions. If you want to return formatted string you should provide a formatting option to the serializer:

```
string test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
```

For example if I try to serialize the object that you provided in an example

```
var response = new
{
    mydata = new object[]
    {
        new
        {
            data = new object[]
            {
                new { x = 1 },
                new { y = 0 }
            },
            frq = 12
        }
    },
    success = true,
    error_message = ""
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
```

I get the following result:

```
"{\r\n  "mydata": [\r\n    {\r\n      "data": [\r\n        {\r\n          "x": 1\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          "y": 0\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      "frq": 12\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  "success": true,\r\n  "error_message": ""\r\n}"
```

So the serialization works as expected. You don't specify how and where you observe the result. Can be that the client or browser trims the string and that's why you don't see a formatting.

By the way, if you use `Newtonsoft.Json`, consider registering it for the ASP.NET Core serialization:

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Tried that with no luck. seems to me that the formatting is not taking effect

Comment: Can you post what you've tried in the question? What library you use for json serialization? It seems to be that you use Newtonsoft.Json. And how do you verify that the json in string wasn't formatted? Can you also post an example value that the string stores?

Comment: ..updated the question

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am getting  \" instead of \r\n after string test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);

Comment: Maybe create a repository in GitHub with reproducible example? There must be something wrong with how you do it.

Comment: I am not able to push my repo. getting time out. i guess it is my network setting, which i have no control over. I updated desvription to include the controller code

Comment: @Mikey check the update to my answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem. By the way, check out this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make sure to provide as much details and context as you can to make it easier for community to help you in future. Cheers.